# On Maximo , How Pass GLDEBITACCT field from PRLINE to CONTRACTLINE after action copy PR lines to Contract

Tags: maximo

Automation script is needed On Maximo , How Pass GLDEBITACCT field from PRLINE to CONTRACTLINE after action copy PR lines to Contract

```
   from psdi.mbo import MboSet
   from psdi.mbo import MboConstants
   from psdi.server import MXServer;
   from java.sql import Statement;
   from java.sql import PreparedStatement;
   from java.sql import Connection;
from java.sql import ResultSet;
from psdi.mbo import Mbo;
import time;

CONTRACTNUM = mbo.getString("CONTRACTNUM");
CONTRACTLINENUM = mbo.getString("CONTRACTLINENUM");

mxserver = MXServer.getMXServer();
userInfo = mxserver.getSystemUserInfo();
currentSet = mxserver.getMboSet("PRLINE",userInfo);
currentMbo = currentSet.getMbo(0);
con = currentMbo.getMboServer().getDBConnection(userInfo.getConnectionKey());
schema = currentMbo.getMboServer().getSchemaOwner();

q= " SELECT PRLINE.GLDEBITACCT FROM PRLINE WHERE PRLINE.CONTRACTNUM ='"+ CONTRACTNUM +"' AND PRLINE.CONTRACTLINENUM ='"+ CONTRACTLINENUM +"' ";

s= con.createStatement();
rs1 = s.executeQuery(q);

while(rs1.next()):
   result = rs1.getString('test');
s.close();
mbo.setValue("CONTRACTLINE.GLDEBITACCT",result  ,MboConstants.NOACCESSCHECK | MboConstants.NOVALIDATION)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.